# Wix MSI Doesn't Launch

Tags: c#, wix, installation, windows-installer

The project was built successfully but when i run the generated MSI it makes its checks and gathers info and then closes and the installer doesn't appear. In task manager i can see that msiexec.exe is running. What is happening? this is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="d52283dd-2703-42a4-b3ef-73726d5e4ec6">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Installer" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{CB56C523-A71F-41C2-8C67-30A864FF253F}">
      <File Source="$(var.EJMS.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From command line try to run

> msiexec /i installerName.msi /l*v log.txt

And look through the installer log to see if its getting caught up somewhere. The install could be silently failing, or even succeeding. You have no UI setup, so it would just go through the install silently. Check for **return value 3** as it generally indicates failures

Comment: well yeah it appeared that it installs silently. and ye its working. thanks a lot. i tho have a question why doesn't msiexec close?

Comment: That's odd behavior, I'm not sure why it wouldn't close automatically after completing the install. Does the log state that the install completed successfully?